# Solr search based on list of terms. Order by max(score) for each term

Tags: lucene, solr

I am trying to query a solr server in order to obtain the most relevant results for a list of terms.

For example i have the list of words "nokia", "iphone", "charger"

My schema contains the following data:
nokia
iphone
nokia iphone otherwords
nokia white
iphone white

If I run a simple query like q=nokia OR iphone OR charger i get "nokia iphone otherwords" as the most relevant result (because it contains more query terms)

I would like to get "nokia" or "iphone" or "iphone white" as first results, because for each individual term they would be the most relevant.

In order to obtain the correct list i would do a query for each term, then aggregate the results and order them based on the maximum score.

Can I make this query in one request?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the "coord". From the [SolrRelevancyFAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ):

```
coord is the coordination factor - if there are multiple terms in a query, the more terms that match, the higher the score
```

You could write your own [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) subclass to ignore the coord or only take the highest value when scoring.

There might be other ways too, you could ask in the [solr-users](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mailing_lists.html) mailing list.

This might also help: [comparing lucene scores across queries](http://markmail.org/message/pl7tx7kca2spo54z)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but writing a custom scoring class isn't possible in my case. I need to use the standard Similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should execute 3 separate searches to me

Comment: Well, i have a list of 4000 terms and a data-set of 1 million rows. Executing 4000 searches is kinda sad.